# Kernel Oops accessing BAR Registers from User Space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to develop a user level driver on Linux for a FC class device (HBA) on a custom powerpc Board. I have mapped the PCI config space as well as BAR registers using the remap_pfn_range() to user space and locked the address space. when I'l trying to access the BAR registers for clearing the mailbox etc from user space, i'm getting a kernel a kernel panic.

Can someone give me pointers to debug the Kernel Panic and verify the PCI config.
Is it possible to do this kind of memory mapping.
TLB seems to have the mapping entries.

lspci O/p :

```
lspci -vvv
00:01.0 Class 0c04: Device 1077:2a31 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Device 1077:0000
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0
    Region 0: Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Region 2: Memory at 80140000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at 87000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at 80100000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [4c] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 1024 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <1us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x8, ASPM L0s, Latency L0 <2us, L1 <2us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot-
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- Retrain- CommClk-
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x8, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range B, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message/WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [88] Vital Product Data
        No end tag found
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=32 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=2 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=2 offset=00001000
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltT- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [154 v1] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
        ARICap: MFVC- ACS-, Next Function: 1
        ARICtl: MFVC- ACS-, Function Group: 0
    Capabilities: [19c v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 08
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [1a4 v1] Transaction Processing Hints
        No steering table available
    Capabilities: [1b0 v1] #19
    Capabilities: [1cc v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 0ns
        Max no snoop latency: 0ns
```

```
<4>[ 3486.328040] Bad trap at PC: fe27fc4, SR: 2d000, vector=102
<4>[ 3486.328104] Bad trap at PC: c000fb94, SR: 29000, vector=102
<4>[ 3486.328143] Oops: Exception in kernel mode, sig: 5 [#1]
<4>[ 3486.328168] PREEMPT DEBUG_PAGEALLOC APP
<4>[ 3486.328197] Modules linked in: qlapci memdev ttyprint
<4>[ 3486.328240] NIP: c000fb94 LR: c000f7cc CTR: 00000000
<4>[ 3486.328272] REGS: c7ffdf10 TRAP: 0102   Not tainted  (2.6.32)
<4>[ 3486.328300] MSR: 00029000 <EE,ME,CE>  CR: 24002484  XER: 00000018
<4>[ 3486.328352] TASK = c4060df0[828] 'app' THREAD: c405e000
<4>[ 3486.328376] GPR00: 00000000 c405ff00 c4060df0 00004000 c405fd88 00000000 ffffffff 00000010 
<4>[ 3486.328440] GPR08: 00000000 00000002 00029002 c405e000 24002482 100aa0fc 00000000 90800000 
<4>[ 3486.328503] GPR16: 00000000 00000003 100a2258 00000000 10038e44 911ff930 00a00000 0ffbe1bc 
<4>[ 3486.328567] GPR24: 00001000 0ffbc124 911ff490 10098a38 0ff7894c 00000011 0ff77ff4 0ff78488 
<4>[ 3486.328665] NIP [c000fb94] do_user_signal+0x8/0xc4
<4>[ 3486.328697] LR [c000f7cc] ret_from_crit_exc+0x0/0x104
<4>[ 3486.328723] Call Trace:
<4>[ 3486.328746] [c405ff00] [c000f7cc] ret_from_crit_exc+0x0/0x104 (unreliable)
<4>[ 3486.328782] Instruction dump:
<4>[ 3486.328804] 4817f901 3d400002 614a1002 7d400124 54290024 8129003c 71200004 40a2ffdc
<4>[ 3486.328865] 71202006 4182fb64 614a8000 7d400124 <806100b0> 70600001 41820058 91a10044 
<0>[ 3486.328932] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

Answer (score 1):

To access PCI resources from user space, call `mmap()` on the appropriate sysfs files, like this:

```c
fd = open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.3/resource0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
ptr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

On PowerPC, this might not work because of a compatibility workaround for X; you should reenable the two code blocks inside `#if 0` in `arch/powerpc/kernel/pci-common.c`.

Answer (score 0):

> "My company has this business plan, which depends on us exploiting the works of all the Linux kernel and userspace developers, going against their wishes of keeping the source code open, but we need to do it in a way that makes it too risky for them to sue us. However, I'm finding it very difficult to do it the legal way. Will someone help me?"

No. The kind of driver you are describing belongs in the kernel. There are literally dozens of similar drivers in-kernel already, and you could easily adapt/build one using those as a guideline. You do not want to, because that would mean you'd have to license the kernel driver using GPLv2 (as the easy way to write the driver is to use the GPLv2'd existing code), and your employers don't want that.

Your employers could easily use another free kernel, say freebsd or openbsd, or one of the proprietary ones, but that too would run counter to their business plan: they wish to exploit Linux. They wish to eat the cake, keep it, and charge others too. And you are here to ask for help to do exactly that: to help you and your employers to avoid the desires of the Linux kernel developers, while exploiting their work.

Selfish much?

The PCI ID, 1077:2a31, indicates a QLogic-based interface chip; you seem to be developing an iSCSI SAN box. There are many driver variants for similar chips in-kernel already, so developing an open-source in-kernel driver would be much easier. If you did it well enough to be accepted upstream, your maintenance work would be much reduced. The only downside is that your employers would have to compete on the merits of their product; in other words, that they would actually have to think up a workable business plan, instead of using the same one they have used for all the Windows stuff they've done for well over a decade now.

Times change. Business models must evolve too.

---

Your chosen approach will not work. You might get it working with a specific kernel version, or if you create a kernel driver (shim) that your userspace components talk to. The kernel-userspace interface in Linux is simply not built to accommodate what you wish to do, you see; the parts that you'd need to rely on don't exist, or change from kernel version to version.

The correct solution to the problems you are facing is to do it in kernel space.

Now, if you were to change your approach, and switch to an open-source kernel driver model, it would be a pleasure to help you.

If you insist on using Linux, considering the hardware and existing code base, you'll almost certainly end up reusing existing GPLv2 code, and thus the kernel driver will have to be open sourced. (Don't take my word for it, though; ask your lawyer to be sure.)

If you insist on keeping your driver closed source, switch to another kernel -- freebsd, openbsd, or perhaps buy a license to one of the proprietary ones.
*Follow the spirit of the licenses, and the communities will help you.*

If you insist on using Linux but keeping your driver closed source, at least have the skill to do it yourself.

---

Edited after djs9999's comments to the above:

Instead of trying to do everything from userspace, you could do an intermediate ("hardware exploration") driver as a character device, a *"shim"* driver. The [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is a very good source of information, and contains a very useful example character driver, *scull*.

The basic idea is that your character driver is opened by the userspace component. The kernel driver initializes the hardware, and maps the needed buffer/mailbox memory, initializes hardware interrupts, and so on. (If you clean them up when the device is closed, your hardware exploration becomes much easier -- no need to load/unload kernel modules, in particular.)

The character driver interface is such that your userspace component can `mmap()` the buffer/mailbox, and use `read()` to receive notifications from the hardware (interrupts, message completions) as messages, and `write()` to send messages from the userspace component to the kernel component, if needed. `mmap()`, `read()`, `write()` each have a different callback, so this is very easy to do in the kernel character driver; again, see the [LDD3](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) *scull* driver example.

(Most developers tend to use `ioctl()` for most of the stuff above, but there is really no need. The `mmap()`/`read()`/`write()` interface is easier and cleaner to implement.)

Now, this gives you a shim driver that allows you to explore the hardware from the userspace application, with a very simple kernel character driver. The application only needs access to the character device node (that is, if you configure the node to be owned by a specific user, your userspace component does not need root privileges), and the kernel character driver will manage all the low-level control.

The reason you might wish to do it this way, is that it is the easiest way to explore the hardware. In many countries, the laws allow you to analyze the behaviour of any closed-source code for interoperability reasons, although most companies separate the exploration and new driver development for legal reasons. Basically, the exploration is used to construct a document, which specifies how the hardware is/must be/can be accessed, to achieve the desired operation.
The new driver does not reuse any code, and is written based on the derived documentation only.

After you have good enough documentation on the hardware, you can start developing the actual open-source driver.

I don't have any FC hardware at hand, and no experience developing such a driver, so I'm mostly useless for helping with developing an FC driver. However, files in [Documentation/scsi/](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scsi/) and especially [Documentatio/scsi/scsi_fc_transport.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scsi/scsi_fc_transport.txt) in the Linux kernel sources ought to be useful; like I said, there is already iSCSI support et cetera in-kernel. The linux-scsi mailing list at kernel.org ([archives at MARC.info](http://marc.info/?l=linux-scsi&r=1&w=2)) is where you could ask for pointers, and perhaps even a mentor to help you develop an actual free driver for your hardware.

Finally, Greg Kroah-Hartmann ([website](http://www.kroah.com/linux/)) is known for helping companies develop free drivers for their hardware; see [this announcement from January 2007](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/free_drivers.html) as an example. If you are working for a company, contacting him for info or better contacts or other help for developing the driver, might be a good idea.

Comment: Well, Thanks for your elaborate comment. I completely agree with your views on using the Linux infrastruture and GPL licensing. Point is well taken but things are the other way around. How about if I'm fighting for replacing the existing proprietry OS with Linux? There is an existing codebase written in a certain way which I want to utilise with Linux.
For prototype, i want minimal code changes and developing from userlevel is my first approach. If that is not possible, I am happy to develop the kernel driver and switch to an open-source kernel driver model.

Comment: And i don't believe in using binary kernel modules. This has nothing to do with Employer and most certainly there are employers who advocate the Linux and support Linux community.

Also, for kernel driver development, you will probably agree that since there is a learning curve associated, most users feel comfortable to develop work in user space, atleast in begining. And that is where I'm, trying to get the things done in easiest possible way based on my skills. I take your point in positive spirit, Surely, I need to improve and I'm working on it.

Comment: Having said that, if my approach is not working because I lack skills , i would want to learn things and improve upon my skills. Here, pardon me for my ignorance but I'm trying to understand technically what is missing which is causing the issue. 
I certainly need strong reasons beyond my poor skills so that I can do the right thing by switching to an open-source kernel driver model.

Comment: Infact, as you said, "you'll almost certainly end up reusing existing GPLv2 code, and thus the kernel driver will have to be open sourced", the kernel component to which user application will interact should be opensourced. I need to understand that inkernel driver what more needs to be done to make it work other than Call mmap() on /sys/bus/pci/devices/DEVICE_ADDRESS/resourceN from the userspace application.

Comment: @djs9999: Okay, I added my suggestion and pointers on how to go about it. In short, assuming you don't yet have enough info on the hardware to develop an actual block/netdev driver from scratch: use a simple kernel character driver instead, doing all low-level manipulation like PCI config and hw interrupts in the driver, so the userspace component only talks to the character driver and nothing else.